# Using :not pseudo-class across components

Tags: reactjs, jss

I have a `<Section>` component:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  section: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
    color: theme.colors.white,

    '& a:not(.button)': {
      color: 'currentColor',
      textDecoration: 'underline',
    },
  },
});
```

And a `<Button>` component:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.light,
    color: theme.colors.dark,
    padding: theme.spacing.default,
  },
});
```

Basically, I'd like to use `<Button>` inside of `<Section>` and not have its color overridden.

I can't use `& a:not($button)` because it's in a different component.

Comment: what do you mean by `this expects .button to be global, while it is not`?

Comment: The generated class is something like `.is-primary-0-24 a:not(.button)`, but my button components generate `.button-0-24`.

Comment: What are you using for the css class name manipulation then?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I just tested is simply adding `!important` to the `<Button>` styles. It feels dirty...

Answer (score 0):

A better solution was to modify the selector to: `a:not([class^="button"])`, which will target JSS generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't override components styles implicitly using selectors. It is a very fragile approach, because it is breaking encapsulation and at some point it will break your styles.

You should either use `color: inherit` in the button component and let parent always define the color or use explicit overrides:

1. Accept a class name in the child, define in parent a css rule with your color. (Good when static)
2. Using theming (Good when static and predefined)
3. Use function values and props http://cssinjs.org/json-api#function-values (Good if highly dynamic)

Comment: So if I have `a: { color: 'red' }` and `select: { backgroundColor: 'red' }` then how do I make my anchors visible? Especially if users create links in a markdown editor, I can't create a `<Link>` component which is obnoxious anyways.

Comment: Now that I think about it my solution was to use `:not` to not override a component's style implicitly?

Comment: If your anchors don't have a component around them, so basically they are part of a Markdown component, then target them with '& a'.